# c# , Http request return unkown chars

Tags: c#, .net, http, request, httprequest

I Have this code

---

```
internal static SourceCookieSTatue LoadSource(string p)
{

    SourceCookieSTatue __Result__ = new SourceCookieSTatue();
    try
    {
        var Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(p.Trim());
        Request.UserAgent = MrHTTP.Chrome_UserAgent;
        Request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
        string x = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        string CokString = MrHTTP.GetCookieString(response.Headers);
        return new SourceCookieSTatue(x, CokString);
    }
    catch (Exception sa) { return new SourceCookieSTatue(sa.Message,false);   

}
```

---

when i send the http request it return chars like these

> ���;Yo#Gz���פ�d7��(QcIsz5�K�d1���d���z��"5Z�X�a   ��!oA`o��Yl
>   ��WH���
>   ����>8#ً`���������{����4㞋??8zp���a�M��0n�F{�����tb?��2��q�
>   i3΃�a,}��Y85��K�+&'�m���mnk{k�r����ѸLw{{;�

when i intercept the request using BURP-SUite it works correctly .

Comment: Try removing the accept encoding

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line:

```
            Request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

You are adding a compression parameter in your request header. You can either remove the compression parameter or you can define the default behavior to decompress your request by adding the following line:

```
            Request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
```